# Differences and best protocol for voip asterisk pjsip

Tags: asterisk

I am currently migrating a switchboard asterisk from sip to pjsip
And I find something new, you can use different protocols like   udp,tcp,tls,ws,wss....
I wonder what protocol is better and safer...
I understand that tls i wss are safer
Currently I only use udp and it seems that everything works fine, But I can also make it to work with every one at the same time.....

I would like you to help me understand what is the use of these protocols and if I would have to use some specific.

Regards,

Answer (score -1):

TCP better if you have bad network(like 3G mobile) or complex NAT. UDP faster setup and most common.

TLS if you need encryption. WSS is for webRTC/websocket(call from browser).